# How to extract folder from file path

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a function that will return the fourth folder within a file path.

For example, say my file path is "C:\Users\Desktop\Programs\Training Log\Folder Database". I would like to extract the "Training" folder and save as variable.

Here is my current function:

```
Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String

    If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
        GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

This function returns the immediate parent folder.  How could I specify a folder other than the immediate parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using this function:

```
Public Function getParentFolder(path As String, Optional level As Integer = 0)
    Dim pathTokens()    As String
    pathTokens = VBA.split(path, "\")
    Debug.Assert level >= 0 And level <= UBound(pathTokens)
    getParentFolder = pathTokens(UBound(pathTokens) - level)
End Function
```

By using `Optional` the default value is 0, so you can use this as a single- or two-argument function. The `level` argument lets you choose how many levels (directories) deep you go.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Split` to get the 4th part.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim MyAr As Variant

    FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\Programs\Training Log\Folder Database"
    MyAr = Split(FilePath, "\")

    Debug.Print MyAr(4)
End Sub
```